# How to adjust the row size without resize column in ListView in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, listview, multiline, word-wrap

I'm trying to have a text from a List View Item in a single row without resize the column size, something like textbox property "Multiline"

In the picture below the column "Descripcion" is adding "..." to the product description, instead of that I want all the description in one row.

[image]

Something Like:

```
Descripcion         Precio
-------------------|-------
All the description|
in one single row  | 80
-------------------|-------
Another item in one|
single row         | 70
-------------------|-------
```

I just tried with something like this:

```
ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem();
row.ListView.Height = 30;
```

but row.Height throw me an exception, any idea how to do this?

Comment: Asked many times before, google "windows forms listview multiple lines per cell" to find the existing SO questions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the height you can use `SmallImageList`, here is an example :

```
private void SetHeight(ListView listView, int height)
{
    ImageList imgLst = new ImageList();
    imgLst.ImageSize = new Size(1, height);
    listView.SmallImageList = imgLst;
}
```

Also to wrap your Column, you could use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html), it's an open source C# wrapper around a .NET `ListView`

Comment: Do you have an example how to do it with the ObjectListView library, I donwloaded it, but don't know how to do that.